# Margins for buttons are not setting in Android programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the following code to generate button objects with a set text, onClick command (more or less), height, width, and margins

```java
    private Button generateButton(String text, char command, int height, int width, int left, int top){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getDP(width),getDP(height));
        lp.setMargins(getDP(left),getDP(top),0,0);
        Button button = new Button(this.getContext());
        button.setText(text);
        button.setLayoutParams(lp);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Command",""+ command);

            }
            private char command;
            private View.OnClickListener init(char var){
                command = var;
                return this;
            }
        }.init(command));
        return button;
    }
```

Along with this method to get the dp

```java
    private int getDP(int size){
        return (int) (size * this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
```

But when I run the app the button have the proper height and width, along with the proper text and onclick action, but they have no margins, they're all bunched up into one corner

The view hierchy according to the Layout Inspector in Android studio goes

```
DecorView
   LinearLayout
      FrameLayout
          FitWindowLinearLayout
             ContentFrameLayout
                CoordinatorLayout
                   ViewPager
                      ConstraintLayout
                         ConstraintLayout
                            Buttons
```

And from what I've read online, LayoutParams has to be from the same class as the layout, as is LinearLayout.LayourParams, or ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams and I've tried all the layout types that made sense to me and still no margins

It might be worth noting this is in a fragment

Comment: Can you share the code where you are adding the generated views to your hierarchy?

Comment: @basilisk 
`((ConstraintLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)).addView(generateButton("On",'a',50,100,16,8));`
Like I said, I've tried using ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams and there's still no margin

Comment: `setMargins` uses pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For views that are children of ConstraintLayout, you need to add horizontal and vertical constraints. Otherwise they layout will not know how to place them, and places them at the top left corner.

You can use the ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams, and set the constraints by

`lp.leftToLeft`, `lp.leftToRight` and similar methods [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.html#leftToLeft)

So for example if you want to place these buttons one after the other vertically, you will constraint each button horizontally to the parent, and vertically to the previous button.

Comment: At this moment, this works (I say at this moment because all I know are the buttons aren't bunched up, they're actually I think where they should be) so thank you

Comment: Great! I will also recommend exploring the ConstraintLayout constraints in the Layout Design tab, as they can get a bit difficult to visualize at times.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setMargins (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

This is the signature for setMargins method. You call the method with right = 0 and bottom = 0. So you will not have the margins on right and bottom. Try to set some values for right and bottom.

Comment: Nope, and I've never had to set margins on all 4 sides, typically just the top and left side. Even in the WYSIWYG layout editor, you can just set the margin of 2, even one side, and Android will still properly show the margin(s)

Answer (score 0):

You should use LayoutParams to set your button margins:`

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourbutton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Depending on what layout you're using you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

And to convert your dp measure to pixel, try this:

```
Resources r = mContext.getResources();
int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
        yourdpmeasure, 
        r.getDisplayMetrics()
);
```

`